SwiftUI popup alert, button action not working the first time
What I want to achieve: when clicking the save button, it pops up a box asking for the name. after user gives a name and hits the confirm button, it performs some actions and dismisses the view (return to the parent view).
here's my code, however, it doesn't perform any actions when I save and confirm the first time. All following attempts works. any idea why it doesn't work for the first time?
    Button(action: {
      self.isShowingNameInput = true
    }) {
      Text("SAVE")
    }
    .alert("Task Name", isPresented: self.$isShowingNameInput, actions: {
      TextField("", text: self.$options.name)  

      Button(action: {
        log("Saved \(self.options.name)")
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      }) {
        Text("Confirm")
      }.disabled(self.options.name.isEmpty)

      Button(role: .cancel, action: {}) {
        Text("Cancel")
      }
    }, message: {})


Remove the .disabled(self.options.name.isEmpty). Note, there is no need for the self.
anymore, remove them. Also you can just use dismiss() with @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

@workingdogsupportUkraine 1) I do want to keep it disabled when the input is empty. 2) it's a good practice to explicitly use self so that readers know it's a struct property

I am not sure if you can have a TextField in the actions of an alert. In general, the data for an alert should not change after presentation occurs and this also applies to the values of state variables that you show in the content of the alert. See Update text inside alert message which relates to a similar issue.
As a workaround, you could consider showing a sheet instead:
struct ConfirmationDialog: View {
    @Binding var options: Options
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Please enter your name")
            TextField("Name", text: $options.name)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Spacer()
            Button {
                print("Saved \(options.name)")
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Confirm")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .disabled(options.name.isEmpty)

            Button(role: .cancel) {
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Cancel")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingNameInput = false
    @State private var options = Options()

    var body: some View {
        Button("SAVE") {
            isShowingNameInput = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingNameInput) {
            ConfirmationDialog(options: $options)
                .presentationDetents([.height(250)])
        }
    }
}


Alternatively, you could implement a custom alert. The answer to the post mentioned above shows an example of how this can be done (it was my answer).
EDIT Ref. the questions in your comment: the reason for implementing the dialog as a separate View is so that dismiss can be used to dismiss the sheet, which I thought was what you were trying to do before. See the documentation for more details about dismiss. However, you don't have to implement it this way - if the sheet would be contained in the view that shows it then it could be dismisssed just by setting the state variable isShowingNameInput back to false. The dialog buttons could then call the dismiss action associated with the containing view instead, in order to go back to the parent view. There was no parent view in your example though.
EDIT2 To have the text field auto-focus, try adding a FocusState variable which you then set to true in .onAppear:
@FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

TextField("Name", text: $options.name)
    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    .focused($isFocused)
    .onAppear { isFocused = true }


thanks for the details. two questions. 1. why do I need a ConfirmationDialog struct? when I just did it inline (copied the content from the struct) to content view it didn't dismiss. 2. by dismiss I'd like to return to the parent view as mentioned but it looks like it doesn't?

@user1385809 Answer updated with more explanation

I got all the dismiss working. however, in my previous attempt with alert, the textfield is auto-focused, but it isn't with your workaround. would it be possible to have it here?

@user1385809 Pleased to hear you're getting nearer to a solution. Answer updated again to show how auto-focus can be implemented too. Ps. If the answer helped, you are welcome to upvote and/or accept it

upvoted. sorry I did try it with focused, and also tried to set it true in many places, but it just didn't get focused. any thoughts?

@user1385809 Did you try it in .onAppear? The code in the answer works for me. Ps. thanks for the upvote!

yes I did. maybe because the full code is a bit complicated. I will spend more time debugging but let me know if you have more insights

I had the same issue, .disabled(self.options.name.isEmpty) is the cause, its interesting to me that the documentation you referenced says the data should not change, as it seems a common thing one would want to do with small bits of text input. Anyways this is a good work around its just odd to me that Alert wouldn't be able to handle this use-case, is there any other digging we can do or file a bug to Apple to change the SDK?

@MadeByDouglas I believe it used to be possible to have content that could change, when implemented using an Alert. Apple, in its wisdom, has made that deprecated.

@BenzyNeez really!? that is strange

I noticed if the alert contains any text fields and you set a button role (cancel/destructive), you might encounter a strange issue where sometimes the button without a role doesn't work.
So, my workaround was to

avoid setting any button roles

My sample code is like below:
Button(buttonText) {
    isAlertPresented = true
}
.alert("Enter your PIN code", isPresented: $isAlertPresented) {
    SecureField(text: $pinCode) {}
       .keyboardType(.numberPad)

    Button("Cancel") { // Don't set role here
        print("Cancel")
    }

    Button("Submit") {
        print("Submit")
        buttonText = pinCode
    }
}


There's a bug in SwiftUI where the textfield cannot be empty when first displaying inside an alert, otherwise you'll have unexpected behavior
Try setting an initial, non empty value to self.$options.name

I was having the same exact issue as the OP and I did as you said and it worked! Sucks though it needs to start with some text, kind of renders it useless.
